# How can I select a table heading which have same class name and not any other unique attribute in web driver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

```
<th id="desc" class="sort" data="aWQ=">S.No</th>
<th class="table_head" data="bmFtZQ==">Customer</th>
<th class="table_head" data="c3R5bGVfbm8=">Style#</th>
<th class="table_head" data="c3R5bGVfZGVzYw==">Style Description</th>
<th class="table_head" data="ZmFicmljX2Rlc2M=">Fabric Description</th>
<th class="table_head" data="YXBwcm92ZWQ=">Status</th>
<th>Action </th>
```

> The able code states that same class name for all columns,The ID & CLASS is assigned only when user selects a column to filter.
>   IN that case how can I select all the columns

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery you can do this:

```
$('th').eq(1) // the "customer" element
$('th').eq(4) // the "fabric description" element
```

in vanilla JS, it's just as simple:

```
document.querySelectorAll('th')[1] // the "customer" element
document.querySelectorAll('th')[4] // the "fabric description" element
```

with this, you can easily select the nth table column, but you have to know the index of the column beforehand.